# How to get Json object using UrlConnection in android?

Tags: android, json

Hi I am very for android just one week ago I come into this technology and in my app I am integrating services.

Here I have used HttpClient for that, but in android 6 I was deprecated.

That's why we have to use URlconnection, but how can we use this Url connection instead of HttpClient?

My code is below.

Please help me.

### my code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;
    ActorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");

        ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actorsList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }


    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {
                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Actors actor = new Actors();
                        actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
                        actor.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
                        actor.setDob(object.getString("dob"));
                        actor.setCountry(object.getString("country"));
                        actor.setHeight(object.getString("height"));
                        actor.setSpouse(object.getString("spouse"));
                        actor.setChildren(object.getString("children"));
                        actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));
                        actorsList.add(actor);

                    }
                    return true;
                }

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if(result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is u r output string?>

Comment: i post my entire code please see once

Comment: do you know the mean of output string?

Comment: json object we can get here i think

Comment: can u please update my code with Urlconnection

Comment: @Krish This is not a code writing service. All the information you need is available on the [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html). Anything beyond that is just asking someone else to do your work for you. Personally, I would recommend using Android Volley instead of using the raw `HttpUrlConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Volley instead. Volley is compatible with almost all APIs.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) on how to do this.